# Label Visibility.Collapsed on empty content WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to figure out how I can make hide a label when it's hidden & visible again when text is set using XAML. I can easily do it with a TextChanged event but there must be a correct way to do it using xaml, right?

I've done my research but I can't find anything that works.

Window1

```
<TextBox Name="nameTxt" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Window2

```
<Label Name="nameLbl" Content="{Binding Name}" />
```

Comment: You can add a Visibility type property to your view model that reflects the presence of text in the Name property and bind it to the visibility of the TextBox or you can bind the Name property to the visibility property and create a StringToVisibilityConverter class to show or hide the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it implements by built-in class in .Net `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanVisibilityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

*Let me show work example:*

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Hello, I am the button" Visibility="{Binding ShowButton, 
   Converter={StaticResource booleanVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private bool _showButton = false;
public bool ShowButton
{
   get { return _showButton; }
   set
   {
      if (value != _showButton)
      {
         _showButton = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("ShowButton");
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to change the `Visibility` of your Button in code, you can make it by this code in `ViewModel`:

```
IsButtonVisible = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what I was doing wrong yesterday but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom converter.

[wpf tutorial value converters](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

You can write the logic to test for string.IsNullOrEmpty and return hidden, otherwise return visible.

This approach is nice as it keeps visibility out of your view model.